# setenv per process?

Tags: c++, setenv

I m assing file name dynamically using setenv as folows:

```
setenv("file.name",filename.c_str,1);
```

I m curious if this is per process?

If i have multiple processes running this code but taking different file names, would there be any collisions?

Lets say I have process 1

```
setenv("file.name",filename1.c_str,1);
```

and process 2

```
setenv("file.name",filename1.c_str,1);
```

would i have any problems doing this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The environment you set with `setenv()` is per process. Essentially it is just a memory area in your process. At least, this is what does on UNIX systems. Unlike `getenv()` it isn't part of either the C or the C++ standard but it is part of POSIX. What it does on non-POSIX systems, if it exists, may be something different.

Comment: I'm sorry for this event - the response I gave wasn't appropriate for the situation.

Answer (score 0):

Environment variables are platform specific.  I don't think setenv() works with Windows, so assuming you are talking about a program running on Linux, you should be fine.  setenv() sets environment variables with process scope (and of course shared amongst forked threads).

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, on all modern operating systems, each process has a seperate environment block which is usually constructed when the process is created.  (e.g. during `NtCreateProcess()` on a Windows system) or the equivalent for Linux/Unix/Other.  `_putenv()` will work on Windows wheras `setenv()` will work on Linux/Unix.

Comment: I can see that `setenv()` is part of POSIX but I didn't see it in C or C++.